# Rapid 3D Spatial Modeling and Data Analysis

Tags: 3d, modeling

I am looking to determine if SketchUp Pro is the appropriate software or if there is a better solution out there for the following purposes.

I need a tool that will allow me to rapidly model 3D spaces for the purpose of very early design.  On a lot of projects, we use Revit to build complex architectural models, and there are a lot of analysis tools available, but they are of limited usage until the model is reasonably far along.  Very early on, I will often have rough room dimensions and layouts and would like to be able to quickly throw "blocks" together with dimensions for the purposes of calculating rooms sizes and being able to lay out equipment within those rooms.

Ideally, the software would have the following features:

- Ability to rapidly create rooms/spaces without time consuming detailing of each and every wall, etc.  -  Something like having rooms represented with blocks
- If room dimensions changed, the "blocks" could be resized/reshaped dynamically.
- Ability to determine surface areas of floors, ceilings, walls, etc.
- Ability to determine room volumes
- Ability to calculated shared areas of walls for adjacent rooms

Comment: Have never really used Sketchup much, and haven't touched it in quite a while now, but I don't think it ever had any capabilities to calculate areas, sums, or volumes or any other data extraction from the model, as far as I know. And apart from BIM software or perhaps some CAD ones I don't think you'll easily find ways to extract that kind of data from a model, at least not earlier than you could with Revit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already working in Revit, why not use Revit's Conceptual Massing tools? they would seem to answer your needs pretty nicely, and you clearly already have the tool.

There is an existing workflow path for SketchUp to Revit, but in many ways, though the SketchUp workflow appeals to many, it's severely limited and not very responsive to changes.

I'd look more closely at Revit's own massing tools.

[Revit Help-MassingTools](http://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2015/ENU/?guid=GUID-A3097388-C28F-4425-877A-406038BCD55F)

[image]